# Error updating SQLAlchemy relationship attribute: 'TypeError: 'email' is an invalid keyword argument for SentCount

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Problem Description:**

I am working on a backend service to track bulk emails for different mailing lists. Each mailing list has subscribers, and emails are sent to these subscribers. I want to store the information about the sent emails in a database, including the count of emails sent for each mailing list.

**Model Structure:**

1. **MailingList:**

   - Attributes: `id` (primary key), `name`
   - Relationships: One-to-Many with `Subscriber`, One-to-Many with `Email`, One-to-One with `SentCount`
2. **Subscriber:**

   - Attributes: `id` (primary key), `email`, `mailing_list_id` (foreign key referencing `MailingList.id`)
3. **Email:**

   - Attributes: `id` (primary key), `subject`, `body`, `sent_at`, `mailing_list_id` (foreign key referencing `MailingList.id`)
4. **SentCount:**

   - Attributes: `id` (primary key), `mailing_list_id` (foreign key referencing `MailingList.id`), `sent_count`

**Issues and Expected Output:**

1. **Error Encountered:**

   - When attempting to update the `sent_count` for a `MailingList` instance using the `update_sent_count` method, a TypeError occurs, stating that 'email' is an invalid keyword argument for `SentCount`.
2. **Desired Behavior:**

   - The goal is to keep track of the total count of unique emails sent for each mailing list.
   - A separate table, `SentCount`, is intended to store this information, and the `update_sent_count` method in the `MailingList` class should dynamically update the `sent_count` field in the `SentCount` table.
3. **Current Code:**

   - An example query might involve getting the total count of unique emails sent for a particular mailing list, and updating the corresponding `SentCount` entry. Code at hand raising `TypeError: 'email' is an invalid keyword argument for SentCount`.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from datetime import datetime

Base = declarative_base()


class MailingList(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mailing_lists"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    subscribers = relationship("Subscriber", back_populates="mailing_list")
    emails = relationship("Email", back_populates="mailing_list")
    sent_emails = relationship("SentCount", back_populates="mailing_list")

    sent_count_entry = relationship(
        "SentCount", back_populates="mailing_list", uselist=False
    )

    def update_sent_count(self, session):
        if self.sent_count_entry is None:
            self.sent_count_entry = SentCount(mailing_list=self)
            session.add(self.sent_count_entry)

        sent_count_query = session.query(func.count(SentCount.id)).filter(
            SentCount.mailing_list_id == self.id
        )
        self.sent_count_entry.sent_count = sent_count_query.scalar()
        session.commit()


class Subscriber(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subscribers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    mailing_list_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("mailing_lists.id"))
    mailing_list = relationship("MailingList", back_populates="subscribers")


class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = "emails"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = Column(String, nullable=False)
    body = Column(String, nullable=False)
    sent_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    mailing_list_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("mailing_lists.id"))
    mailing_list = relationship("MailingList", back_populates="emails")


class SentCount(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sent_counts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mailing_list_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("mailing_lists.id"), unique=True, nullable=False
    )
    sent_count = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    mailing_list = relationship("MailingList", back_populates="sent_count_entry")


# database URL
database_url = "postgresql://...."
engine = create_engine(database_url)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create mailing lists
weekly_newsletter = MailingList(name="Weekly Newsletter")
business = MailingList(name="Business")

# Create subscribers
subscriber1 = Subscriber(
    email="subscriber1@example.com", mailing_list=weekly_newsletter
)
subscriber2 = Subscriber(email="subscriber2@example.com", mailing_list=business)
subscriber3 = Subscriber(
    email="subscriber3@example.com", mailing_list=weekly_newsletter
)
subscriber4 = Subscriber(
    email="subscriber4@example.com", mailing_list=weekly_newsletter
)

# Create emails
email1 = Email(subject="Subject 1", body="Body 1", mailing_list=weekly_newsletter)
email2 = Email(subject="Subject 2", body="Body 2", mailing_list=business)
email3 = Email(subject="Subject 3", body="Body 3", mailing_list=business)
email4 = Email(subject="Subject 1", body="Body 1", mailing_list=weekly_newsletter)

# Add objects to the session
session.add_all(
    [
        weekly_newsletter,
        business,
        subscriber1,
        subscriber2,
        subscriber3,
        email1,
        email2,
        email3,
        email4,
    ]
)

# record the sending of an email for the "Weekly Newsletter" mailing list
weekly_newsletter = (
    session.query(MailingList).filter_by(name="Weekly Newsletter").first()
)

# Update the sent count dynamically
weekly_newsletter.update_sent_count(session)


email_to_send = session.query(Email).filter_by(subject="Subject 1").first()

# Create a Sent record
sent_record = SentCount(
    mailing_list=weekly_newsletter, email=email_to_send, sent_count=1
)

# Update the sent count for the mailing list
weekly_newsletter.sent_emails.append(sent_record)


# Commit the changes to the database
session.commit()

# Count subscribers for each mailing list
subscribers_count_query = (
    session.query(MailingList.name, func.count(Subscriber.id).label("subscriber_count"))
    .join(Subscriber)
    .group_by(MailingList.name)
    .all()
)

print("Subscribers Count:")
for result in subscribers_count_query:
    print(f"{result.name}: {result.subscriber_count} subscribers")

# Count emails sent for each mailing list
emails_count_query = (
    session.query(MailingList.name, func.count(Email.id).label("email_count"))
    .join(Email)
    .group_by(MailingList.name)
    .all()
)

print("\nEmails Sent Count:")
for result in emails_count_query:
    print(f"{result.name}: {result.email_count} emails sent")
```

**Expected Output:**

- After running the `update_sent_count` method, the `SentCount` table should be updated with the correct `sent_count` value for the specified mailing list.

```sql
-- Example Expected SentCount Table
| id | mailing_list_id | sent_count |
|----|------------------|------------|
| 1  | 1                | 5          |  -- Assuming 5 unique emails sent for 'Weekly Newsletter'
```

**Resolution:**

- Ensure that the `SentCount` class references the correct foreign key column (`mailing_list_id`) and that the `update_sent_count` method in the `MailingList` class correctly calculates the unique count of sent emails for the mailing list.

Comment: You have no `email` column in `class SentCount`.

Comment: The only table with that column is `Subscriber`. I don't see any relationship between `SentCount` and `Subscriber`.

Comment: Actually I am referencing the relationship between `SentCount` and `MailingList` in `update_sent_count` method.

Comment: The problem is `SentCount(
    mailing_list=weekly_newsletter, email=email_to_send, sent_count=1
)` You're trying to specify the `email` column in the `SentCount` row that you're creating, but there is no such column.